# JQuery datatable error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

so i am getting the common error "DataTables warning: table id=myTable - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1". the solution I have tried online is not really working out for me. so basically I am testing a local JSON file and using data table ajax method to populate the table. i cant seem to figure out what i did wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "./test.json", false);
    request.send(null)
    var responseMain = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    var my_array = responseMain.feed.entry;
    $("#totalnum").html(my_array.length);

    var obj_stage = [];
    $.each(my_array, function (index, value) {
        
        obj_stage.push(value.content.F_Form1);
        console.log("inside each", obj_stage)
    });


    console.log("out side each", obj_stage)
    console.log("what type",typeof obj_stage);


    $('#myTable').DataTable({
        "ajax": obj_stage,
        "columns": [
            { "data": obj_stage["-flowState"] },
            { "data": obj_stage["-flowState"] },
        ]
    });
});

//console.log("value",value.content.F_Form1["-flowState"])
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./test.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="totalnum"></h1>
    <table id="myTable" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Stage Name</th>
                <th>Asap ?</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can try,  directly use `data: obj_stage` instead of ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly call the object because it is already loaded in `obj_stage`.

No need to do this `{ "data": obj_stage["-flowState"] },` instead `{ "data": "-flowState" },` the first one would not populate the column because the objects were already in an array (*and you can only access array by using its index*), DataTables will to that for you just use its property name or the key.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", "./test.json", false);
    request.send(null)
    var responseMain = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    var my_array = responseMain.feed.entry;
    $("#totalnum").html(my_array.length);

    var obj_stage = [];
    $.each(my_array, function (index, value) {
        obj_stage.push(value.content.F_Form1);
    });
    //if(my_array.length === obj_stage.length ){
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "data": obj_stage,
            "columns": [
                { "data": "-flowState" },
                { "data": "-flowState" },
            ]
        });
    //}
});
```